next-auth token iat exp jti and token renewal, browser exit
next-auth CredentialsProvider
It is being processed with
If you decode the jwt after calling the getToken method in middleware without setting the jwt in callbacks,
iat exp jti is displayed. Can I edit or update this iat, exp?
And I often saw sources issuing a new "user.token" from "authorize" in "CredentialsProvider". Why does "authorize" issue a new "user.token" when "next-auth" automatically issues a jwt token?
Subsequently, if user.token is specified in the jwt of "callbacks" among "authOptions", doesn't "next-auth" generate a jwt token?
Lastly, how do I renew the jwt token or session when the screen is moved, refreshed, or extended (extension of validity time)?
And is there a way to expire the session when the browser closes?
Thanks for reading.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
